# Can arguments passed to function that is assigned to a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, pysnmp

I am working with PySNMP. Throughout my program I need to perform various SNMP transactions that reuse the same arguments for different functions `nextCmd`, `getCmd`, and `setCmd`. For simplicity of this post, let's say that I am only working with the `getCmd` functions. I am aware that this function can operate on multiple OID's, but that is not my current need. Below I have just pulled the systemName for a managed device.

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData(snmp_community, mpModel=1),
           UdpTransportTarget((target, 161)),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', 0))
           ))
```

Let's say that later in my script I need to poll the up time from the same device. Instead of having to create most of the code again, like so:

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData(snmp_community, mpModel=1),
           UdpTransportTarget((target, 161)),
           ContextData(),
          ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysUpTime', 0))
           ))
```

How can I store the `getCmd` function with the other `static` arguments and just pass the `OID` into the variable/function so that I can minimize my code?

Comment: `ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', 0))` cahnges to: `ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysUpTime', 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is just to wrap it in another function:

```
def standard_call(oid):
    cmd = getCmd(SnmpEngine(), 
                 CommunityData(snmp_community, mpModel=1), 
                 UdpTransportTarget((target, 161)), 
                 ContextData(),
                 # Plug in the oid
                 ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', oid, 0)))

    return next(cmd) 

standard_call('sysUpTime')
standard_call('sysName')
```

Note how the part that changes was made a parameter, and everything else was made the body of the function. Generally, this is how to approach "generalization problems".

---

This could be expanded by constructing the `ObjectTypes` from tuples passed in:

```
def standard_call(*identity_args):
    # Construct the ObjectTypes we need
    obj_types = [ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(*arg_tup)) for arg_tup in identity_args]

    cmd = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                 CommunityData(snmp_community, mpModel=1),
                 UdpTransportTarget((target, 161)),
                 ContextData(),
                 # Spread the list of ObjectTypes as arguments to getCmd
                 *obj_types)

    return next(cmd)

standard_call(('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', 0),
              ('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysServices', 0),
              ('CISCO-FLASH-MIB', 'ciscoFlashCopyEntryStatus', 13))
```

Comment: What if I wanted to pass `standard_call`  multiple parameters so that it builds something `ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', 0)),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysServices', 0)),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('CISCO-FLASH-MIB', 'ciscoFlashCopyEntryStatus', 13)),`

Comment: @adamz88 `getCmd` is var-arg?

Comment: @adamz88 `getCmd` takes a variable number of arguments? You can pass as many `ObjectType`s as you want?

Comment: @adamz88 Nvm, just found the documentation for it. I'll write an answer when I get to my desktop. What data should be allowed to be changed? Just the two strings passed to `ObjectIdentity`?

Comment: thank you! The two strings passed to `ObjectIdentity` plus the integer passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `functools.partial` for binding some parameters?

```
from functools import partial

from pysnmp.hlapi import *

getCmd = partial(
    getCmd, SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'),
    UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
    ContextData())

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
        getCmd(ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)),
               ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysUpTime', 0))))
```

Comment: could you show how this could be turned into a module callable from an other script? Also, is there a way that one only has to pass `('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)` when invoking it?

Comment: I do not quite understand what do you need re module callable. If you want to pass just the args I think you need to a wrapper function, may be a decorator...